How would one formalize the mathematical operations of Tensors in deep learning libraries (TensorFlow, Pytorch, Numpy)?
I'm having trouble in understaning how to formalize some of the operations done in libraries such as Numpy, TensorFlow, Pytorch and others.
From what I know, some basic operations such as summing are well defined by tensors, but there are others such as broadcasting, "squeezing" (removing a unimportant dimension from a tensor, e.g. (4, 1, 2) -> (4,2)), and reshaping that makes sense in a machine learning perspective, but I can't quite make the connection to mathematics.
Besides that, something that bothers me is that the machine learning community usually ignores the formal definition of a tensor and its operations, just seeing it as n-dimensional arrays and treating it as some sort of intuitive higher dimension matrix, which in practice works but leaves a gap in the intrinsic understanding of them.

At least in numpy there are no tensors in the mathematical sense. Only ndarrays that sometimes get mislabeled (at least from a math perspective) as tensors by computer people.

In machine learning the word “tensor” simply means multidimensional array. That is all.

Broadcasting, reshaping, etc can all be defined as certain linear transformations from one space of multidimensional arrays to another.

The squeeze is the easy one. It does not make sense to write $x^i$ if $i\in{1}$; I have an object with a single element so I do not need an index to enumerate it. In the same way I can write ${A^j}_i$  for a mixed tensor that represents a matrix (lets say $j$ indexes columns and $i$ indexes rows). But if I tell you that $i \in {1}$ then I might as well write $A^j$ since this is a matrix with a single row which is another name for a (transpose) vector. So you could say that tensors come  pre-squeezed!

" the machine learning community usually ignores the formal definition of a tensor": which definition do you have in mind? Definitions aren't right or wrong; either they are useful or they aren't, and each discipline has it own set of definitions. If I'm reading a physicist, I expect a tensor to have the usual transformation properties, but I don't expect a machine learning author to respect this. There are analogies between physics (statistical mechanics) and machine leaning, but they shouldn't be pushed beyond what is useful IMHO.

Start with a space of multilinear functions of n variables from n distinct linear vector spaces to the underlying field.
Construct the Cartesian product of the n vector spaces as a formal list of ordered vectors and identify via both multinearities all elements in the Cartesian product by an easy to follow receipt:
Fix a basis of 1-forms for the representation of the the multinear functions, add a 0.th dimension and collect all coefficient products.
Do the same with all vector products such that the overall product of coefficients is collected in the 0.th component. Organize the the basis products simply by 0,1 for existence or nonexistence in a 1-form- or vector basis product.
This is in short the effect of identifying all tensors with respect to their different representation modulo  differences and multiples that make up the kernel in this representation contraction, if the effect is observed on feeding the as arguments to the simple basis products of linear 1-forms.
Evaluation of tensor forms and vectors may be understood like long numerical addition in two rows, where each contraction in a column produces  a number, that is moved left as a factor to the coefficient collector place in position 0.
